# Prevent selectmenu widget from closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have a selectmenu widget with a bunch of options. I'd like to add a "show more" button as the last option which would then either load in more options and refresh the widget or just toggle their visibility to show them if they had already been loaded in but were not visible (either method would be ok, I don't mind).

The problem is that click on the "show more" option then closes the select menu itself! There must be a work around for this, as allowing multiple options to be selected doesn't close the widget when you click on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I can include a data-placeholder tag or a disabled tag. This would achieve my goal and I could style it to look the same. Do they fire an event when clicked? If so, how could I call it?

Answer (score 0):

yes, disabled option could be helpfull

But first give it an id, something like:

```
 <option id="other" disabled style="color: black; text-align: center;">Other choices</option>
```

then the js part ( with jQuery):

```
function goToOther(){
    var url = "http://qwant.com";
    window.location = url;
}


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#other').on('click', function(){
       goToOther();
    });
});
```

Comment: That didn't work because disabled makes it non-clickable... Any other ideas?

Comment: That's clickable if it's a  jquery-mobile  
Selectmenu Widget.

Comment: Thanks @piem, but unfortunately I still can't get it working, have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjs8b9yd/).

Comment: If you set data-native-menu to "true", it works. After that all is css

Comment: Right ok, but I need it to be a jQuery mobile styled object. Is there a way to make it work with data-native-menu=false?

Answer (score 0):

Set data-native-menu to true and enhance the menu jqm style with css, something like:

```css
.fakeList{background-clip: padding-box;
 background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
 border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
 border-left-style: solid;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
 border-right-style: solid;
 border-right-width: 1px;
 border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
 color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 20.8px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 opacity: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 padding-bottom: 11.2px;
 padding-left: 16px;
 padding-right: 40px;
 padding-top: 11.2px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-decoration-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
 text-decoration-line: none;
 text-decoration-style: solid;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 text-shadow: rgb(243, 243, 243) 0px 1px 0px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

then in the js :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('option').addClass('fakeList');
    $('#showMore').on('click', function(){
       alert("do show more");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @piem, it's still not working for me, though perhaps this is a browser compatibility thing. I am testing on Safari on Mac, though I actually only need it to work on Safari on iOS. It's for a web app I'm building for my company, and they issue us iPhones, so I'm not even bothering to test on other platforms at this stage. If I set data-native-menu=true, then I get a iOS generated scroll wheel which won't even let me settle on the "disabled" option. Not sure this strategy is going to work. Perhaps I'll need to build my own popup and do it all manually...